# Insert a migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

So here's the story. We have a product in source control using Entity Framework Code First migrations. For the sake of this question, there are two branches, development and production. At the moment the development branch has several migrations that are not in the production branch, but they follow sequentially from the last migration in the production branch.

Now, we need to make a small schema change to the production branch. We do this by adding a migration. This is then published to the production site.

So, how do we integrate these changes into the development branch? The migrations in the development branch must, necessarily, be descended from what's on the production site, but we just inserted a new migration on the production site. This means that when we merge into the development branch, the migrations fail because there's an out-of-order migration.

So, in my development branch, is there any way to insert the migration from the other branch, shunting the existing migrations down the list?

Comment: Do changes in the production branch conflict with the changes already made in the development branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dealt with this when merging changes from different developers. In doing some research for this answer, I came across [this handy article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn481501.aspx) which probably explains it better than I can. Alas, you're stuck with me. A couple things to note:

1. Entity Framework doesn't directly compare the database to your classes every time. Instead, it compares an `edmx` model that it generates.
2. Because of this, you will get a warning when trying to update that says

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled…

Although it *will* actually perform the update. The error is referring to the snapshotted(?) `edmx` that it compares.

The easiest way is to add a blank 'merge migration'. Here are the steps from the article:

> 1. Ensure any pending model changes in your local code base have been written to a migration. This step ensures you don’t miss any
>      legitimate changes when it comes time to generate the blank migration.
> 2. Sync with source control.
> 3. Run Update-Database to apply any new migrations that other developers have checked in.
>
>    **Note**:if you don’t get any warnings from the Update-Database command
>      then there were no new migrations from other developers and there is
>      no need to perform any further merging.
> 4. Run Add-Migration [pick_a_name] –IgnoreChanges (e.g. Add-Migration Merge –IgnoreChanges). This generates a migration with all the
>      metadata (including a snapshot of the current model) but will ignore
>      any changes it detects when comparing the current model to the
>      snapshot in the last migrations (meaning you get a blank Up and Down
>      method).

Comment: `.edmx` files aren't used in EF code-first development

Comment: yes, they are. They just aren't used by the developer. The `Model` column in `__MigrationHistory` is a GZipped version of a base64 encoded `edmx`. This is compared to the base64 encoded `edmx` that's stored in the `resx` file for each migration.

Comment: You can see [here](http://www.tecsupra.com/how-to-decode-the-model-column-of-the-migrationhistory-table-in-ef-migrations/) an example of the decoded model.

Comment: Maybe it was a nitpicking, but I just wanted to point out, that there aren't any `.edmx` **files**. Also I'm pretty sure, that the `Model` column isn't used in the code-first development. When generating a new migration, the current model is compared to the model from the latest `.resx` file not to the model from DB.

Comment: Ok ok, you got me. I replaced the word *file* with *model*.

Comment: and, I think you're right about the model from the resx file, that's what I originally wrote in the post. And now I'm curious, what is the record in the table used for?

Comment: The blank `-IgnoreChanges` migration was exactly what was needed. Thanks for saving me a lot of bother.